# Storing and retrieving Golang slice, struct and slice of struct in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, go

Let say I have a *table* named `PEOPLE` which store rows of `Person`. However, the `Person` contains **slice**, **struct** and **slice of struct**, i.e. the *Superpower*, *Vehicle* and *FriendList* fields respectively.

How should I store and retrieve those values in **Postgresql** with **Golang**? I can't find any practical tutorial related to this problem. Use custom data types, or JSON, or ORM method, or building custom functions to deal with these? Many opinions out there, but I still can't figure out a working way to solve this problem, please help.

I am using [Ozzo-dbx](http://github.com/go-ozzo/ozzo-dbx) , however, any solutions is welcome.

Can someone provides a working example? Sorry if this newbie question irritates you, but I already tried for few days, and keep failing... (T_T)

```
type Transport struct {
    Brand string
    Size  int
}

type Friend struct {
    Name         string
    IsProgrammer bool
}

type Person struct {
    ID         int
    Name       string
    Superpower []string   //slice
    Vehicle    Transport  //struct
    FriendList []Friend   //slice of struct
}
```

Comment: You can store `slice`, `struct` and `slice of struct` values in JSON format, and other values `as is` (so `ID` as `int`, `Name` as `string` etc). It will be logical :)

Comment: How are the _SuperPower_, _Vehicle_, and _FriendList_ properties stored in the database? Do you control that decision or are there related tables for them? If it's up to you then you have many choices; if the database structure is already set then you just have to handle those associations...

Comment: I wish to store those fields (*SuperPower*, *Vehicle*, and *FriendList*) as if the data types in Golang. This is the **easiest**. Hopefully, those fields can be stored without JSON encoding, then that is the **fastest**. If it is possible to store without relative tables with association, than that will be **elagant**. If possible, I wish to access  the database with *dot notation*, such as `SELECT Person.Vehicle.Brand ...`, then this may beautifully **implemented**... is it possible? :)

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you should create separate tables for Superpowers, Vehicles, and Friends.

If the relationships between one of these tables and the People table is many-to-one or one-to-one you can add foreign keys to them. If the relationship is many-to-many you should create a linking table that will hold the fkeys of the related records.

To store the data you can insert/update each record individually with simple SQL query strings and `database/sql`.

After that you can create table views that would aggregate the data you want per one person into a single row so that you don't pollute your Go code with complex SQL strings. Then you define simple SQL select query strings in Go and execute them with `database/sql`.

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your suggestion... Hmmm... the website front-end uses too much nested object as that will ease their workflow... Nested objects and arrays are everywhere... Haha... I read about **custom data types** in Postgresql, hope that will be my saviour... Hmmm... Anyway, thank you for your suggestion... will try to implement the relationship table if can't find any better solution :)